# Primitive and Wrapper return types java

Tags: java

Why does not Java allow to override method as follows?

```
class Test1{
    Integer test(){
        return 5;
    }
}
class Test2 extends Test1{
    int test(){
        return 4;
    }
}
```

It produces int not compatible with integer error?

Comment: How is it overriding then? ;)

Comment: int and Integer are not the same, look over the return types of your `test` methods and it should be become clear

Answer (score 2):

You should really try googling `overriding methods return type`  [here](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=9UuZW-bSNoje5gKZ-5_4Ag&q=overriding%20methods%20return%20type&btnK=Google%20Search&oq=overriding%20methods%20ret&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30l8.767.7974..9630...0.0..0.283.2938.13j4j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0j0i131j0i10.E5eQaIw3bq4)

> Yes it may differ but their are some limitations. Before Java 5.0, when you override a method, both parameters and return type must match exactly. In Java 5.0, it introduces a new facility called covariant return type. You can override a method with the same signature but returns a subclass of the object returned.

so `int` is primitive and `Integer` is wrapper class, no relation between them